# Android: Random Sound FX on Button Click

Tags: android, button, random, soundpool

I'm trying to play a random sound FX on a button click using the soundpool. This works in the emulator but not on my device. Any clues?

```
public class enc extends Activity {   
private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";

private SoundPool soundPool;
private HashMap<Integer, Integer> soundsMap;
int SOUND1=1;
int SOUND2=2; 
int SOUND3=3;
int SOUND4=4;
int SOUND5=5;
int SOUND6=6;
int SOUND7=7;
int SOUND8=8;
int fSpeed = 1;

Random random = new Random();
int hit = random.nextInt(6)+1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //SoundPool
    soundPool = new SoundPool(4, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    soundsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    soundsMap.put(SOUND1, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit1, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND2, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit2, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND3, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit3, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND4, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit4, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND5, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit5, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND6, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.hit6, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND7, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.spell, 1));
    soundsMap.put(SOUND8, soundPool.load(this, R.raw.kill, 1));


    setContentView(R.layout.enc);

}


public void setButtonClickListener() {
    Button wepb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uwep);
    wepb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, "----------------------------SFX: " + hit);
            playSound(hit, fSpeed);
            hit = random.nextInt(6)+1;
                    }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: what do you mean when you say it doesn't work on a device?

Comment: When I install it on my phone, the sound won't play. If I call a sound from the pool without using a random integer, it works just fine. I had the same problem when I tried using the mediaplayer

Comment: Are the random numbers getting generated properly?  Can you post the log messages?

Comment: Yeah, the tag I have in the button returns a random number everytime. The emulator plays the audio fine. When I click the button, a random sound plays. It's when I try it on my phone is where I have problems. R.raw.spell and R.raw.kill play fine when called (code not included) and they are not randomized. But hit1-hit6 won't play (on phone)

Comment: When you try to run it on your phone is logcat displaying the right hit value.

Comment: I just checked it and it is getting the right value. The code also read the the sample was not ready. Im using mp3s and from what've I've read, 2.0 only works with OGG files. I'll try converting them and see if that works.

Comment: converting my mp3's to OGG solved to problem. Thanks! If you had never asked me to check my logcat on my phone, I never would have seen the not ready warning. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was using MP3 files and apparently, Android 2.0+ only works with OGG files. Converting all of them from MP3 to OGG fixed it. All is well!